# FPGA: Divide range by fixed number using a look-up table

Tags: math, signal-processing, vhdl, fpga, lookup-tables

I have implemented a block in an FPGA which supports hardware multiplication. This block does some division by using hardly any logic elements because it's able to use some internal DSP.

This block has to be ported to another design, but here I have 2k less logic elements and no hardware multiplier.

My thought would be to implement this division with a look up table in memory, simply because I have 60 kbit available, but I have a hard time finding the right way to do it. Here's what I need to do:

Divide the numbers from 62720 to 65279 by 20 using very few logic elements. I only get 128 different results after rounding the numbers, so the table shouldn't be that heavy, but the problem for me is to remove all the similar results and still use the table to look up the result for the exact division.

The first entries of the table look like this:

```
62720/20 = 3136  
62721/20 = 3136  
62722/20 = 3136      
62723/20 = 3136  
62724/20 = 3136  
62725/20 = 3136  
62726/20 = 3136  
62727/20 = 3136  
62728/20 = 3136  
62729/20 = 3136  
62730/20 = 3137  
62731/20 = 3137  
62732/20 = 3137  
62733/20 = 3137   
62734/20 = 3137   
62735/20 = 3137  
62736/20 = 3137    
62737/20 = 3137    
62738/20 = 3137  
62739/20 = 3137  
62740/20 = 3137    
62741/20 = 3137  
62742/20 = 3137  
62743/20 = 3137  
62744/20 = 3137  
62745/20 = 3137  
62746/20 = 3137  
62747/20 = 3137  
62748/20 = 3137  
62749/20 = 3137  
62750/20 = 3138  
62751/20 = 3138  
62752/20 = 3138  
62753/20 = 3138   
62754/20 = 3138    
62755/20 = 3138   
...
```

For every result I have 20 similar, except the first 3136 which only gives me 10 similar results. My thought was to write a couple of lines for this pattern, but simply can't figure it out.

Please give me your thoughts on this. It doesn't have to be the full solution, just some inputs because I'm stuck :) Thank you.

Comment: This would be a very easy thing to shove into a Block RAM.  Which FPGA are you using?  How many Block RAMs do you have available?

Comment: Subtract 62710 (not 62720, to make the first range the same size as the others.). Notice that 20=5*4 so divide by 4 (omit the two LSBs). You now have a much smaller range to fit into the LUT. Also subtract 3072 from each LUT entry. (You only need to set 2 bits to add it back in : no adder necessary). To do more (e.g. divide by 5)  would take some mathematical analysis to ensure you didn't round incorrectly.

Comment: @BrianDrummond  make this an answer! We need more answers in the VHDL tag and less questions answered in a comment.

Comment: Done. It's really too short for an answer and there are probably better options which would take more work to get good answers, so I was hoping someone else would jump in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subtract 62710 (not 62720, to make the first range the same size as the others.). Notice that 20=5*4 so divide by 4 (omit the two LSBs). You now have a much smaller range to fit into the LUT.

Also subtract 3072 from each LUT entry. (You only need to set 2 bits to add it back in : no adder necessary).

The result is less than 1024 deep by 8 wide, 1 BlockRam in some FPGA technologies.

To do more (e.g. divide by 5) would take some mathematical analysis to ensure you didn't round incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you Brian. Since I have only 128 different results my thought was that it should be possible to have a table with only these 128 entries. Your suggestion gives me "less than" 1024, but couldn't that be made smaller? Or didn't I just understand it correctly?

Comment: It can be made smaller with some obvious tricks, however these involve either division by 5, or multiplication by  a scaled and rounded version of 1/5 (which can be simplified), and you'd need to verify that after scaling and rounding you'd get the correct output for every input. At which point : is it worth the time and effort? (It's a nice exercise if time isn't a consideration, and might be a salutary lesson in the difficulties of getting rounding right...)

Comment: The alternative you're suggesting is a table of input values, indexed by the output. That also works - BUT - you have to search the entire table for each new input. How many cycles have you got, and how big is the search engine going to be in hardware?

Comment: I am a little confused. How can the table you are suggesting have only 1024 entries when I have 2559 different input values? I must be missing something when reading your explanation. Thank you once again.

Comment: From the answer: "so divide by 4" giving you 600+ values.

Comment: This morning I implemented this with succes. Thank you.